# How does one create 2D speech bubbles with tails that follow a specific position relative to some other object?

Tags: animation, tracking, text-object

i.e. in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1fhYZdn1pE&t=4m20s

The speech bubble tails follow the figures' heads and seem to resize, yet the speech bubble itself looks flat relative to the camera. How to achieve this?

Note how the figures can also obscure the speech bubble.